# Raphaeljs: specify the spectrum of getColor()

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using the raphaeljs library and I would like to specify the colors given by the [`getColor`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#getColor) function.
If this is possible, how to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The only argument the function takes is the brightness. Here's the [code taken from v1.5.2](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/dbe241f4c5310dd9bf3b451c538d78c6c4a0e288/raphael.js#L453)

```
R.getColor = function (value) {
        var start = this.getColor.start = this.getColor.start || {h: 0, s: 1, b: value || .75},
            rgb = this.hsb2rgb(start.h, start.s, start.b);
        start.h += .075;
        if (start.h > 1) {
            start.h = 0;
            start.s -= .2;
            start.s <= 0 && (this.getColor.start = {h: 0, s: 1, b: start.b});
        }
        return rgb.hex;
    };
```

Comment: It would be possible to redefine `R.getColor` with a new starting point - at the moment it starts with a hue of 0, which is red. Each iteration adds 0.075 to the hue and takes 0.2 from the saturation. Play around with the start hue and changes to the saturation and you can get some interesting effects.